# Clean implementation of nested / complex Android Room entities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I want to use the Android Jetpack Room library in a personal project of mine but I'm having trouble understanding how to deal with a lot of nested list objects.

A **WorkoutSession** has a list of **Exercises**.  An **Exercise** has a list of **Reps**.  I have separate DB entities and business logic models.

```
@Entity(tableName = "workout_session")
data class WorkoutSessionEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val workoutSessionId: Long = 0,
    val name: String = ""
    
)
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "exercises")
data class ExerciseEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val exerciseId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "workoutSessionId") val workoutSessionId: Long,
)
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "reps")
data class RepsEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Long = 0,
    val weight: Float = 0f,
    val reps: Int = 0,
    val order: Int = 0,
    val exerciseId: Long = 0,
)
```

In order to retrieve the relevant Exercises for Workouts and Reps for Exercises from the DB, I am using relation classes such as:

```
data class ExerciseWithReps(
    @Embedded val exercise: ExerciseEntity,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "exerciseId",
        entityColumn = "exerciseId"
    )
    val reps: List<RepsEntity>)
```

```
data class WorkoutWithExercisesAndReps(
    @Embedded val sessionEntity: WorkoutSessionEntity,
    @Relation(
        entity = ExerciseEntity::class,
        parentColumn = "workoutSessionId",
        entityColumn = "workoutSessionId",
    )
    val exercises: List<ExerciseWithReps>
)
```

Im unsure deciding what is the cleanest way to then use ExerciseWithReps and WorkoutWithExercisesAndReps. It doesn't really make sense to me to pass around WorkoutWithExercisesAndReps, since its a long class name, and has DB related classes in it. I have two solutions I'm exploring.

1. Mapping those back to the internal models for WorkoutSessionData and ExerciseData such as below:

```
data class ExerciseEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val exerciseId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "workoutSessionId") val workoutSessionId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "movement_id") val movementDataId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "template_id") val templateId: Long? = null

)

data class ExerciseData(
    val exerciseId: Long,
    val workoutSessionId: Long,
    val exercises: List<RepsData> = emptyList()

)

fun getExercise(exerciseId: Long): Flow<ExerciseData> {
    exerciseRepository
        .getExerciseWithReps(exerciseId)
        .map {
            // Map the ExerciseWithReps object back to an ExerciseData object with the list of exercises
      }

}
```

or 2.  Create new models for the relation objects and pass those around instead?  I started to do this but I wonder if I'm missing something obvious about why this is wrong?

```
data class ExerciseRelation(
    @Embedded val exercise: ExerciseDataEntity,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "exerciseId",
        entityColumn = "exerciseId"
    )
    val exerciseReps: List<RepsEntity>,
   ...
)

fun ExerciseRelation.toInternalModel() = Exercise(
    exerciseData = exercise.toInternalModel(),
    reps = exerciseReps.map { it.toInternalModel() }.toList()
)
```

```
data class Exercise(
    val exerciseData: ExerciseData,
    val reps: List<RepsData> = mutableListOf()
)

fun Exercise.toRelationModel(): ExerciseRelation =
    ExerciseRelation(
        exercise = exerciseData.asEntityModel(),
        exerciseReps = reps.map { it.asEntity() },
    )
```

```
class ExerciseData(
    val id: Long = 0,
    val workoutSessionId: Long = 0,
)

fun ExerciseData.asEntityModel() = ExerciseDataEntity(
    exerciseId = id,
    workoutSessionId = workoutSessionId,

)
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "exercises")
data class ExerciseDataEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val exerciseId: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "workoutSessionId") val workoutSessionId: Long
)

fun ExerciseDataEntity.toInternalModel() = ExerciseData(
    id = exerciseId,
    workoutSessionId = workoutSessionId,
)
```